# Android: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent

Tags: java, android, android-intent, notifications, native

I am trying to send a notification using Alarm Manager, the code is working fine on the lower SDK versions like 26 below. The android implicit background ban is not letting the notification to broadcast.

find code below for BroadcastReceiver :

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

System.out.println("AlarmReceiver-Worked");

MainActivity.initNotificationChannels(context);
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "default")
       .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
       .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)                                      
       .setContentTitle(intent.getStringExtra("title"))
       .setContentText(intent.getStringExtra("text"))
       .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
       .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
  }
 }
```

Manifext.xml

```
<receiver android:name="com.x.Controllers.Notification.AlarmReceiver"
          android:enabled="true"
          android:exported="true">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);                           
notificationIntent.setAction("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
notificationIntent.putExtra("title", notificationData.getString("title"));
notificationIntent.putExtra("text", notificationData.getString("text"));

PendingIntent broadcast = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, i, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), broadcast);
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all

> not able to go past this error

which error? no log, no info what isn't working... for which actions this `BroadcastReceiver` is registered? is this for `BOOT_COMPLETED` or smth else?

besides that

```
private static boolean notificationChannelsInitialized = false;

if (notificationChannelsInitialized) {
    return;
}
```

it will always `return` in here, you are setting this flag to `true` later in this method, it will never happen.

also don't use `static` flag, just check that `Channel` already exists

```
NotificationChannel channel = manager.getNotificationChannel("default");
notificationChannelsInitialized = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 26 || channel != null;
```

on API below 26 just assume it is there

Comment: Background execution not allowed: receiving Intent { act=android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] flg=0x14 (has extras) } to com.x/.Controllers.Notification.AlarmRecei
    ver

Comment: why do you create `notificationIntent` and `stackBuilder`? both aren't used anywhere in code... `pendingIntent` is created basing on `intent` which is argument for `onReceive` and shouln't be re-broadcasted again for shure... try to replace `pendingIntent` creation with this line `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);`. Also read how to ask question on SO properly, I'm still not shure when this error occurs, your description is messy... is `Notification` even showing?

Comment: well, you have asked question with `this error`, but didn't described what is happening exacly and didn't posted exception log. next instead in edited question you have posted log in comment... I can see numerous problems in your code, two pointed in answer/suggestion and next in comment, have you tried to fix them?

Comment: and here you have next problem: `BOOT_COMPLETED` will setup your `static boolean notificationChannelsInitialized` to `true` and because of second `if` in `onResume` this method won't produce any next `Notification` as long as this `static` field will be kept in memory. I would advice you to create separated method for checking and creating `Channel`, and always running code for showing `Notification` after that, without any `if`. for now try to remove `static` word and check if it works, next clean up your code.. I just want to help you, but you have posted incomplete question with lot of bugs

Comment: I have changed almost everything in my code, the basic idea was not to use BOOT_COMPLETED, it was just to test. Also, the error is because of the implicit intent ban in Android API 26 and above. I am trying different soluting, but they ain't working for me.